# How can I use @UIBinder with CheckBox ValueChangeEvent?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I am trying to get this to work:

```
@UiField
CheckBox showDeleted;

@UiHandler("showDeleted")
public void onShowDeletedClicked(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> ev) {
    ...
}
```

I get these errors from the GWT Compiler:

```
Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
[WARN] The method 'getAssociatedType()' in 'ValueChangeEvent' does not return Type<? extends EventHandler>.
[ERROR] Parameter 'ValueChangeEvent' is not an event (subclass of GwtEvent).
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this to work? For now I will just add a handler manually but the @UIBinder version is much nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT bug [6323 Comment 3](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6323#c3) provides a simple workaround for getting the ui handler annotation to function. Thanks to Roy!

Answer (score 3):

See GWT issue [6323](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6323)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your import is wrong? Is this for sure `com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent`?